# Making a JFreeChart visible in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jfreechart

I have an index.JSP with a form, and an img tag.
The form refers to a servlet that builds the chart, setting it in a session and redirecting back to `index.jsp` (so to could read it as a ServletOutputStream from `BytesFromSession`).
Image is not shown..
In web.xml I mapped a urlPattern of ControllerURL.

index.jsp:

---

```
...
<img src = "/BytesFromSession" > </img>
```

Controller.java

---

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
...

private HttpSession session;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

JFreeChart c = buildChart(); // builds the JFreeChart

session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("tbl", c);

response.sendRedirect( "index.jsp" );
}
```

BytesFromSession.java

---

```
public class BytesFromSession extends HttpServlet {

private ServletOutputStream outputStream;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

try {

    outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    JFreeChart c = (JFreeChart) request.getSession().getAttribute("tbl");
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(outputStream, c, 300, 400); // <---- writing table as JPEG to outputStream

} finally {
 outputStream.close();
  }
 }

}
```

### Edit

Saving chart to a file and redirecting back to index.jsp helped.
Still not sure why saving it in a session didn't.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Is the BytesFromSession servlet called at all?

Comment: Yes - no result. It's as if outputStream doesn't exist. Thought of making it a byte[], but not sure how.
AFAIU, source of image in 'index.jsp' calls it.

Comment: What I meant: Is the servlet called at all?

Comment: No. No output from it whatsoever.

Comment: I could get the chart from session, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
view.forward(request,response);
```

instead of

```
response.sendRedirect( "index.jsp" );
```

**Edit**

I changed the method name **processRequest** to **doGet** in `BytesFromSession.java`
and simply removed the / from img tag like `<img src="BytesFromSession">`

BytesFromSession is mapped in web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>BytesFromSession</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.test.BytesFromSession</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>BytesFromSession</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/BytesFromSession</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I could get the image from chart stored in session that way without having it to be saved to a path. Hope that helps you too.

Comment: It does get rid of the redirecting, but now the graph is shown in whole page, instead just in the image at `index.jsp` (it is deployed at Controller.java  with `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(outputStream, c, 300, 400);`
  and doesn't return). Any ideas?

Comment: You can now see the graph on index.jsp or on a different page ?..if it is displayed on index.jsp, have u tried setting the width and height attributes of <img>

Comment: Removed without any change. :/